# How can I use web-deploy on github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, web-deployment

I have my domain and my hosting through one.com and I'm tired of moving individual files through filezilla and wanted to automate that process using github actions.
I guess I'll start out by saying I'm completely new to this and this is my first time trying to setup an action. Basically what I want is to just push the code to my github repo and then it gets build and sent to my host. Kinda like how it is with Netlify.

I stumbled upon this https://github.com/SamKirkland/web-deploy which should do the trick. I've seen tutorials using this method on youtube, but I guess they have a different provider than I do making it easier.

This is what information I have to go off of and I hope it will be enough to set it up:

Host: ssh.one-example.com
Username: one-example.com
Password: the one you chose for SSH in your Control Panel
Port: 22

and this is what I put in the yml file:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
name: Publish Website
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy Website Every Commit
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name:  Get Latest Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name:  Sync Files
        uses: SamKirkland/web-deploy@v1
        with:
          target-server: ${{ secrets.ftp_host }}
          remote-user: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
          private-ssh-key: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
          destination-path: ~/destinationFolder/
```

I've tried having the target server both be ssh.one-example.com (obviously using my own here) and I've tried one-example.com@ssh.one-example.com

But I'm ending up with the following error when the action is running:

```
Error: Error: The process '/usr/bin/rsync' failed with exit code 255
```

So safe to say I'm a little lost and would like some guidance on how to make it work. Is it what I'm typing that's the issue, is it the host? And if so how do I fix it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try an [SSH action](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action) first, to see if you actually can open an SSH session. This is just for testing the connection: try and execute on the remote server a trivial command (`ls`, or `pwd`)

Then, regarding your current original action, check the error messages *before* your "`The process '/usr/bin/rsync' failed with exit code 255`".
See as an example of previous error messages [`SamKirkland/web-deploy` issue 5](https://github.com/SamKirkland/web-deploy/issues/5) (not yet resolved).